# How do i write a custom function to show value counts of each variable in a dataframe along with levels?

Tags: python, pandas

I have written some of code for the below but unable to get write code to display value counts for each levels

```
def info(data):
    return pd.DataFrame({"Data Type":data.dtypes,
                         "No of Levels":data.apply(lambda x: x.nunique(),axis=0)})
```

Output

```
   Data Type     No of Levels        Levels
A   int64                 3         [1 2 3]
B   int64                 8         [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
C   int64                 6         [1 2 3 4 5 6]
D   object                4         ['Apple' 'Mango' 'Grapes' 'Orange']
E   object                3         ['Cauliflower' 'Potato' 'Tomato']
F   int64                 2         [0 1]
G   int64                 2         [1 0]
H   int64                 2         [1 0]
```

Desired Output

```
   Data Type     No of Levels        Value Counts                  Levels
A   int64                 3       1:100; 2:150; 3:200            [1 2 3]
B   int64                 8       0: 100; 1:200; 3:300...    [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
C   int64                 6       0: 100; 1:200; 3:300...    [1 2 3 4 5 6]
D   object                4       Apple:5,Mango:150...       ['Apple' 'Mango' 'Grapes' 'Orange']
E   object                3       Cauliflower:5,Potato:150...['Cauliflower' 'Potato' 'Tomato']
F   int64                 2       0: 100; 1:200              [0 1]
G   int64                 2       0: 100; 1:200              [1 0]
H   int64                 2       0: 100; 1:200              [1 0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create a python `dict` as follows

```
dict((x,l.count(x)) for x in set(data))
```

[image]

Comment: `def info(data):
    return pd.DataFrame({"Data Type":data.dtypes,
                         "Null Count":data.isnull().sum(),
                         "Value Counts":dict((x,data.count(x)) for x in set(data)),
                         "No of Levels":data.apply(lambda x: x.nunique(),axis=0)})

info(df)`

When i try to run this code, its throwing me an error: ValueError: No axis named Day_No for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
and in the Day_No, it has values of 1 to 30 
Please correct it if i made a mistake in merging the code.

Comment: @saiswasthika can you add a sample of your data set?